# BeautifulSoup: How do I extract all the <li>s from a list of <ul>s that contains some nested <ul>s?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm a newbie programmer trying to jump in to Python by building a script that scrapes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000s_in_film and extracts a list of "Movie Title (Year)".
My HTML source looks like:

```
<h3>Header3 (Start here)</h3>
<ul>
    <li>List items</li>
    <li>Etc...</li>
</ul>
<h3>Header 3</h3>
<ul>
    <li>List items</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Nested list items</li>
        <li>Nested list items</li></ul>
    <li>List items</li>
</ul>
<h2>Header 2 (end here)</h2>
```

I'd like all the `li` tags following the first `h3` tag and stopping at the next `h2` tag, including all nested `li` tags.

```
firstH3 = soup.find('h3')
```

...correctly finds the place I'd like to start.

```
firstH3 = soup.find('h3') # Start here
uls = []
for nextSibling in firstH3.findNextSiblings():
    if nextSibling.name == 'h2':
        break
    if nextSibling.name == 'ul':
        uls.append(nextSibling)
```

...gives me a list `uls`, each with `li` contents that I need.

Excerpt of the `uls` list:

```
<ul>
...
    <li><i><a href="/wiki/Agent_Cody_Banks" title="Agent Cody Banks">Agent Cody Banks</a></i> (2003)</li>
    <li><i><a href="/wiki/Agent_Cody_Banks_2:_Destination_London" title="Agent Cody Banks 2: Destination London">Agent Cody Banks 2: Destination London</a></i> (2004)</li>
    <li>Air Bud series:
        <ul>
            <li><i><a href="/wiki/Air_Bud:_World_Pup" title="Air Bud: World Pup">Air Bud: World Pup</a></i> (2000)</li>
            <li><i><a href="/wiki/Air_Bud:_Seventh_Inning_Fetch" title="Air Bud: Seventh Inning Fetch">Air Bud: Seventh Inning Fetch</a></i> (2002)</li>
            <li><i><a href="/wiki/Air_Bud:_Spikes_Back" title="Air Bud: Spikes Back">Air Bud: Spikes Back</a></i> (2003)</li>
            <li><i><a href="/wiki/Air_Buddies" title="Air Buddies">Air Buddies</a></i> (2006)</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><i><a href="/wiki/Akeelah_and_the_Bee" title="Akeelah and the Bee">Akeelah and the Bee</a></i> (2006)</li>
...
</ul>
```

But I'm unsure of where to go from here.

---

Update:

**Final Code:**

```
lis = []
    for ul in uls:
        for li in ul.findAll('li'):
            if li.find('ul'):
                break
            lis.append(li)

    for li in lis:
        print li.text.encode("utf-8")
```

The `if`...`break` throws out the LI's that contain UL's since the nested LI's are now duplicated.

Print output is now:

> - 102 Dalmatians(2000)
> - 10th & Wolf(2006)
> - 11:14(2006)
> - 12:08 East of Bucharest(2006)
> - 13 Going on 30(2004)
> - 1408(2007)
> - ...

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. You've already done what you have in your question title and are asking how to fill a table/object/something. Please update your question to reflect that (and indicate what you mean by a table - database table or dictionary or something else or you don't know).

Comment: I didn't mean to obfuscate my question with that last sentence, so I'll clarify it. Now I have a list of <ul>s with child <li>s that may or may not contain a nested/child <ul> (with more <li>s). I'm unsure of how to extract all the lis. I'll change the title to better reflect the nested UL question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`.findAll()` works for nested `li` elements:

```
for ul in uls:
    for li in ul.findAll('li'):
        print(li)
```

Output:

```
<li>List items</li>
<li>Etc...</li>
<li>List items</li>
<li>Nested list items</li>
<li>Nested list items</li>
<li>List items</li>
```

Comment: print(li.text) would extract the items without the html.

Answer (score 13):

A list comprehension could work, too.

```
lis = [li for ul in uls for li in ul.findAll('li')]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_list_test")
soup =   BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
w3schollsList = soup.find_all('body')
for w3scholl in w3schollsList:
    ulList = w3scholl.find_all('li')
    for li in ulList:
        print(li)
```

Note: here is to get the "li" inside the div we made