# parsing HTML using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to read a list on a webpage using the BeautifulSoup module in python. The HTML code is as follows :

```
...
<ul id="sidebarmenu1">
<li><a href="Business">Business</a></li>
<li><a href="Warfare">Chinese</a></li>
</ul>
...
```

I parse the document using BeautifulSoup. Now I want to loop through the elements of the list. So I use the next_siblings attribute as follows :

```
first_element = soup.ul.li
for items in soup.ul.li.next_siblings :
    <statements>
```

But, this gives the following error :

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Can anybody please tell me how to read the next li tag. Since obviously there is another li tag at the same level, that should be in the next_siblings list.

Isn't there a way to access all the li tags at the same level. findAll gives **all** the tags nested within a given structure.

Answer (score 1):

borrowing from @elssar 's answer, I used this code :

```
main_list= soup.find('ul', attrs= {'id': 'sidebarmenu1'}
for li in main_list.findAll('li',attrs={},recursive=False):
    ul = li.find('ul')
    if ul == None :
        #do something
    else:
        navigate(ul)
```

where navigate(item) is the recursive function :

```
def navigate(item):
    for con in item.findAll('li',attrs={},recursive=False):
            ul = con.find('ul')
            if (ul == None):
                #do something
            else:
                navigate(ul)
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362981/beautifulsoup-how-do-i-extract-all-the-lis-from-a-list-of-uls-that-contains). It uses findAll() for nested elements.

Not sure if that's entirely what you want, but it might be a start.

Comment: isn't there a way to find only the tags at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

You do something like this -

```
main_list= soup.find('ul', attrs= {'id': 'sidebarmenu1'}
elements= main_list.findAll('li')
for link in elements:
    #do something
```